# Change location of the glue table

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-emr, aws-glue

I've created glue table (external) via terraform where I din't put location of the table.
Location of the table should be updated after app run. And when app runs it receives an exception:
`org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Error: ',', ':', or ';' expected at position 291 from 'bigint:bigint:bigint:bigint:bigint:bigint:bigint:bigint:bigint:bigint:bigint:bigint:bigint:bigint:string:string:smallint:smallint:smallint:decimal(12,2):decimal(12,2):decimal(12,2):bigint:string:bigint:string:timestamp:timestamp:bigint:bigint:bigint:bigint:bigint:string:string:decimal(12,2) :bigint:timestamp:string:bigint:decimal(12,2):string:bigint:bigint:timestamp:int' [0:bigint, 6::, 7:bigint, 13::, 14:bigint, 20::, 21:bigint, 27::, 28:bigint, 34::, 35:bigint, 41::, 42:bigint, 48::, 49:bigint, 55::, 56:bigint, 62::, 63:bigint, 69::, 70:bigint, 76::, 77:bigint, 83::, 84:bigint, 90::, 91:bigint, 97::, 98:string, 104::, 105:string, 111::, 112:smallint, 120::, 121:smallint, 129::, 130:smallint, 138::, 139:decimal, 146:(, 147:12, 149:,, 150:2, 151:), 152::, 153:decimal, 160:(, 161:12, 163:,, 164:2, 165:), 166::, 167:decimal, 174:(, 175:12, 177:,, 178:2, 179:), 180::, 181:bigint, 187::, 188:string, 194::, 195:bigint, 201::, 202:string, 208::, 209:timestamp, 218::, 219:timestamp, 228::, 229:bigint, 235::, 236:bigint, 242::, 243:bigint, 249::, 250:bigint, 256::, 257:bigint, 263::, 264:string, 270::, 271:string, 277::, 278:decimal, 285:(, 286:12, 288:,, 289:2, 290:), 291: , 292::, 293:bigint, 299::, 300:timestamp, 309::, 310:string, 316::, 317:bigint, 323::, 324:decimal, 331:(, 332:12, 334:,, 335:2, 336:), 337::, 338:string, 344::, 345:bigint, 351::, 352:bigint, 358::, 359:timestamp, 368::, 369:int]`

This exception kind of represents fields which were defined in terraform.

From aws console I couldn't set location after table was created. When I connected to AWS EMR which uses Glue metastore and tried to execute same query I receive same exception.

So I have several questions:

1. Does anybody know how to alter empty location of the external glue table?
2. The default location of the table should looks like that `hive/warehouse/dbname.db/tablename`. So what is the correct path in that case in EMR ?